# spark dataframe not successfully written in elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, hadoop, pyspark

I am writing data from my spark-dataframe into ES. i did print the schema and the total count of records and it seems all ok until the dump gets started. Job runs successfully and no issue /error raised in spark job but the index doesn't have the supposed amount of data it should have.
i have 1800k records needs to dump and sometimes it dumps only 500k , sometimes 800k etc.
Here is main section of code.

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
        .config('spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead', '4096') \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()

    final_df = spark.read.load("/trans/MergedFinal_stage_p1", multiline="false", format="json")

print(final_df.count()) # It is perfectly ok
final_df.printSchema() # Schema is also ok

## Issue when data gets write in DB ##
final_df.write.mode("ignore").format(
       'org.elasticsearch.spark.sql'
    ).option(
       'es.nodes', ES_Nodes
    ).option(
       'es.port', ES_PORT
    ).option(
       'es.resource', ES_RESOURCE,
    ).save()
```

My resources are also ok.

Command to run spark job.

`time spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --jars elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12-7.14.1.jar    --master yarn  --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 6g     --executor-memory 3g --num-executors 16 --executor-cores 2 main_es.py`